# PyTables/Pandas: Is writing to HDFStore safe within context?

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I'm trying to make my code more resilient to prevent the kind of problems that you rarely see, but which are just a matter of time until they happen.

This specific bit of code is taking rows from a MongoDB, doing some parsing, transforming the parsed row into a pandas DataFrame with one row, and now I want to store that. HDF files have the good read properties and some good write properties (e.g. append one DataFrame row) but it's not clear to me if the writes are safe.

Schematically, here's the code that I'm concerned about:

```
import pandas as pd

# some stuff....

for row in mongo:
    row_parsed = parse(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(row_parsed)
    with pd.HDFStore(filepath) as store:
        store.append(key=key, value=df, format="table")
```

My question is: how safe is this? For example, if various problems occur inside the `with` context (for example an exception or a power outtage) can the HDF file be corrupted?

According to PyTables [documentation](http://www.pytables.org/FAQ.html#is-pytables-safe) it would appear that the answer for the case of power outtages is Yes, it can be corrupted. However, for the case of various exceptions or system events, the answer should depend on exactly what the `with` context is doing, right? So, what should I consider that I'm protected against?